# Problems with "Try,Except,Finally" in Defining method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem with a code segment I've been working on.

```
def cmdPerm():
    try:
        Permission = ""

        if Permission == "":
            Permission = str(browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/content/div/div[8]/div[2]/card[1]/content/div/p[1]/strong"))
        if Permission == "":
            Permission = str(browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/content/div/div[8]/div[1]/card[1]/content/div/p"))
        if Permission == "":
            Permission = str(browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/content/div/div[7]/div[2]/card[1]/content/div/p/strong"))
        if Permission == "":
            Permission = str(browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/content/div/div[7]/div[2]/card[1]/content/div/p[1]/strong"))

        if Permission != "":
            fileAdd.write("\n" + Permission)
    except:
        unused = ""
    finally:
        unused = ""
```

The problem is that this function always returns Exception. No errors in compile/runtime or anything like that, but it always goes to except: no matter what I input. I tried changing the value of "Permission" to "ABC". I understand that this would stop the whole XPath thingy, but the last IF statement in my code should work. And no it's not any additional imports I need, I have more code above which follows the same template and they all work. It's just this one that argues with me.

EDIT: To explain the code alittle, It's basically a webscraper that checks a certain part of the website for info, if it can't find anything on that part, it goes to the next Xpath supplied in the code until it finds one. If it can't find the data in any of the XPaths it will except: and continue with the rest of the code (which it does). If any of the XPaths work, it wont check the rest of the XPaths and instead write the info to a file.

Kind regards,

Comment: Can you paste the exception into the question please?

Comment: Excuse me I might have been unclear, there's no exception. I mean that instead of going through my different IF statements it goes directly to Except: (Stopping the execution of the method)

Comment: How do you distinguish `except` and `finally` handlers with given code?
Are you sure this is not an issue with your xpath expressions?

Comment: The XPaths are fine, as I said even when completely avoiding those IF statements by setting "Permission = "ABC" the code goes directly to except. I'm not using except or finally in this segment of the code, so unused = "" is just placeholder code as I need them to be there to not get compile error on try:

Comment: Well, if you're doing everything right, it's either XPath does not matches anything, or there should be exception backtrace…

Comment: Never use a bare `except`; use `except Exception` instead (which won't catch exceptions like `SystemExit` that you almost certainly don't *want* to catch). If you suspect an exception is being raised, at least capture and and log the exception to help with debugging: `except Exception as exc: print(exc); unused = ""`.

Comment: Well as I said if I change "Permission = "ABC"" the XPaths aren't even executed so I know there's no problem with those. And yes I would hope that there would be an error, right now I'm clueless.. that's why I wrote here

Comment: @chepner I will try this, thanks! :)

Comment: @chepner for some reason the code addition you gave me seems to kinda work. Now It does write ABC to file if I input it manually as Permission. I will continue to try to fix it myself and post the solution here later :)

Comment: can you remove the except entirely and include the raised exception in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify this to

```
def cmdPerm():
    paths = [
        "/html/body/content/div/div[8]/div[2]/card[1]/content/div/p[1]/strong",
        "/html/body/content/div/div[8]/div[1]/card[1]/content/div/p",
        "/html/body/content/div/div[7]/div[2]/card[1]/content/div/p/strong",
        "/html/body/content/div/div[7]/div[2]/card[1]/content/div/p[1]/strong"
    ]

    for p in paths:
        try:
            permission = browser.find_element_by_xpath(p)
            fileAdd.write("\n" + permission)
            break
        except NoSuchElementException:
            pass  # Ignore the error and try the next path
     else:
         # Put code here to execute if none of the paths worked
         pass
```

Note the specific exception being caught. You want to ignore `NoSuchElementException` to continue the loop, but you aren't prepared to do anything sensible for any other exception, so don't catch them.

Comment: Wow this was way more effective yes, my code above works, but your example has design! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Working code is below. It was the XPaths that stopped it from working, I know that atleast 3 out of 4 XPaths will not function each time this script is run, that's why I have it setup this way. But the problem was that if the first one didn't work, it threw exception and therefor stopped the code. I'm kinda new to Python so I still have a lot of stuff to learn. The below code works as intended though. Thanks for all the help!

```
def cmdPerm():
    try:
        Permission = ""
        if Permission == "":
            Permission = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/content/div/div[8]/div[2]/card[1]/content/div/p[1]/strong")
    except:
        try:
            Permission = ""
            if Permission == "":
                Permission = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/content/div/div[8]/div[1]/card[1]/content/div/p")
        except:
            try:
                Permission = ""
                if Permission == "":
                    Permission = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/content/div/div[7]/div[2]/card[1]/content/div/p/strong")
            except:
                try:
                    Permission = ""
                    if Permission == "":
                        Permission = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/content/div/div[7]/div[2]/card[1]/content/div/p[1]/strong")
                except:
                    unused = ""
    finally:
        Permission = str(Permission.text)
        fileAdd.write("\n" + Permission)
```

Comment: You don't need the `if` statements; the condition is always going to be `True`, because you just initialized the value to the empty string. Further, you don't need to reinitialized `Permission` each time; either `find_element_by_xpath` returns a valid string, or an exception is raised, in which case nothing new was assigned to `Permission`.